# Parent with one child higher than child height (white-space)

Tags: html, css, layout, menu

I've got a menu with a vertically oriented un-ordered list.
The childs's width is set to 100% and it's the only child in it's parent. The parent has no height set.

The parents' height stretches to the height of the children, but it is stretching too far (about 2-3px).
The light blue area is the body of the parent. You can clearly see the height is higher than the list with anchors. If you inspect the list with anchors, you'll see that the height is smaller.

[image]

Here's the code snippet:

```css
#navigation {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #213059
}
#navigation > nav {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#navigation > nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#navigation > nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
}

#navigation a.nav_button {
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#b4ddb4+0,83c783+17,52b152+33,008a00+67,005700+83,002400+100;Green+3D+%231 */
    background: #4E7C87; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #253767 67%, #2d2f62 83%, #213059 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #253767 67%, #2d2f62 83%, #213059 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #253767 67%, #2d2f62 83%, #213059 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4e7c87', endColorstr='#304480',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation a.nav_button:hover {
    background: #4E7C87; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #3c3c8b 67%, #4d63aa 83%,#4d84e5 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #3c3c8b 67%, #4d63aa 83%,#4d84e5 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #3c3c8b 67%, #4d63aa 83%,#4d84e5 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4e7c87', endColorstr='#4473c8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<section id="navigation">
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">Portfolio</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</section>
```

I believe it has something to do with the child being 100% in width. Some invisible force is cause the browser to draw "something" behind the child element, causing the extra white space.

Am I on the right track? Can you help me solve this?

Comment: Thank you for a well written question

Comment: @LcSalazar That's nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER after COMMENTS:

Add `vertical-align: bottom;` to the `#navigation > nav` rule. Since that is an `inline-block`, it would otherwise be aligned at the baseline, which causes some remaining descender space (as visible in your question).

I would also recommend to add `overflow: auto;` to the `ul` (to wrap the floating `li`s in it):

```css
#navigation {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #213059
}
#navigation > nav {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#navigation > nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#navigation > nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
}

#navigation a.nav_button {
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#b4ddb4+0,83c783+17,52b152+33,008a00+67,005700+83,002400+100;Green+3D+%231 */
    background: #4E7C87; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #253767 67%, #2d2f62 83%, #213059 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #253767 67%, #2d2f62 83%, #213059 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #253767 67%, #2d2f62 83%, #213059 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4e7c87', endColorstr='#304480',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation a.nav_button:hover {
    background: #4E7C87; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #3c3c8b 67%, #4d63aa 83%,#4d84e5 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #3c3c8b 67%, #4d63aa 83%,#4d84e5 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #3c3c8b 67%, #4d63aa 83%,#4d84e5 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4e7c87', endColorstr='#4473c8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<section id="navigation">
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">Portfolio</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes, sadly that doesn't change anything. I use inspect element (ctrl + shift + c) to see the result btw.

Comment: It does - I added a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I haven't been clear enough. Wrapping is not the problem. Look at the picture in my question. I've used inspect element to highlight `section#navigation`. The blue-ish marked area is the body but it's higher than the children. I wish to remove the extra height because there is no content (it's about 2-3 px)

Comment: I've updated my question (explanation above the image)

Comment: I've updated my answer - see the addition at the bottom

Comment: Yes, that actually works and sounds logic as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Float the `li` tags, not the `a` tags. However, you have to change it to `display: block` on the `a` tags

```
#navigation > nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```css
#navigation {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #213059
}
#navigation > nav {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
#navigation > nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#navigation > nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left; /* Added this*/
}

#navigation a.nav_button {
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#b4ddb4+0,83c783+17,52b152+33,008a00+67,005700+83,002400+100;Green+3D+%231 */
    background: #4E7C87; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #253767 67%, #2d2f62 83%, #213059 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #253767 67%, #2d2f62 83%, #213059 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #253767 67%, #2d2f62 83%, #213059 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4e7c87', endColorstr='#304480',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    color: white;
    display: block; /* change from float:left to this */
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation a.nav_button:hover {
    background: #4E7C87; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #3c3c8b 67%, #4d63aa 83%,#4d84e5 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #3c3c8b 67%, #4d63aa 83%,#4d84e5 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4e7c87 0%, #4d5d87 17%, #2e4369 33%,
    #3c3c8b 67%, #4d63aa 83%,#4d84e5 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4e7c87', endColorstr='#4473c8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<section id="navigation">
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">Portfolio</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_button">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</section>
```

Okay, it was the `display: inline-block` at `#navigation > nav`. If you don' want `overflow: hidden`, change the `float:left` on the `li` tags to `display: inline-block`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, this doesn't help though. Try visualizing the element using the select element feature (ctrl + shift + c). the parent still has like 5px of white space underneath the menu.

Comment: I've updated my question because I don't think the issue at hand is explained well enough :)

Comment: Alright, that did it, thanks. I don't fully understand how `display:block` and `overflow:hidden` affects the height of it's parent though... Without `overflow:hidden`, the parents' inner height collapses. I'll look into it.

Comment: Sorry but I went with the answer of Johannes because his explanation makes more sense. Thanks though

Comment: Your welcome! Thanks for the upvote! `float: left` makes the element have no height. `Overflow: hidden` makes the parent respect the height. If you don't want to use `overflow:hidden`, change the `float:left: on the `li` tags to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: No sweat :). That does makes sense as well... I guess every solution is a hack these days.